# Kendo grid Angular UI Horizontal scrollbar issue

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

If I have only one record in kendo grid that time horizontal scroll bar is not working.

I tried to resolve this issue using CSS but still is not resolve.

```
.k-grid-content {
      overflow-x: scroll !important;
}
```

Comment: From Review: Please better describe what is the issue. Please edit your question, and avoid posting comments with details to your own question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As long as the Grid is scrollable (the default) and the sum of widths of all columns with set widths is greater than the width of the Grid, the horizontal scrollbar will appear regardless of the number of items (unless there are 0 items):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   template: `
       <kendo-grid [data]="gridData">
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" width="500"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" width="500"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" width="500"></kendo-grid-column>
        <kendo-grid-column field="Discontinued" width="500"></kendo-grid-column>
       </kendo-grid>
   `
})
export class AppComponent {
   public gridData: any[] = products;
}

const products = [{
   "ProductID": 1,
   "ProductName": "Chai",
   "UnitPrice": 18.0000,
   "Discontinued": true
 }
];
```

[PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/JF4zDXeBTmxg3oCqNhVm?p=preview)

Comment: Actually I were using "Perfect Scrollbar" that's why i faced this issue once I removed Reference and it's working properly, Thanks for your time.